# subquery returns multiple results

Tags: sql, subquery

I had 3 tables I gather data from into one temp table if I execute

Select * From #TempTable
I get

```
DOG     AGE GENDER  T_id    I_name                      T_name
Fiddo   4   M       1       comfy bed                   bed
Daisy   7   F       1       red mat                     bed
Fluffy  1   M       1       old rug                     bed
Fiddo   4   M       2       bowl with paw               bowl
Daisy   7   F       2       chinese food tray           bowl
Fiddo   4   M       4       fancy leather collar        collar
Daisy   7   F       4       nametags on a string        collar
Fluffy  1   M       4       custom-stamped mardingale   collar
Daisy   7   F       3       blue ball                   toy
Fluffy  1   M       3       chewy bone                  toy
```

For the resultset I am looking for I have this query I execute against this table

```
Select Distinct DOG,
                AGE,
                GENDER,
                BED = COALESCE((Select I_name from #TempTable where DOG = DOG and T_name = 'bed'), NULL),
                BOWL = COALESCE((Select I_name from #TempTable where DOG = DOG and T_name = 'bowl'), NULL),
                TOY = COALESCE((Select I_name from #TempTable where DOG = DOG and T_name = 'toy'), NULL),
                COLLAR = COALESCE((Select I_name from #TempTable where DOG = DOG and T_name = 'collar'), NULL)
From #TempTable
```

I'm getting the error

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Because as far as I can discern DOG is not resolving to one value any tips on syntax I'm not getting right to use the row value of DOG? I want 3 rows in the result set for Daisy, Fiddo, and Fluffy with their Age, Gender, bed, bowl if they have one or NULL, their collar and their toy if they have one or NULL.
Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Subquery in `SELECT` can only return one value.  Your subquery obviously returns more than one rows.

Comment: Can you provide an output example data for this query: Select I_name from #TempTable where DOG = DOG and T_name = 'bed'

Comment: Each of your subqueries must return only one value in order to store the value in the select. The condition DOG = DOG is the one who is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
WITH Result
AS (
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
PIVOT 
(
MAX(I_name) FOR T_name IN ([Bed],[Bowl],[Collar],[Toy]) 
) AS PIvotTable
)
SELECT Dog, Age, Gender, Max(bed) AS [Bed], max(bowl) [Bowl], max(collar) [Collar], Max(Toy) [Toy]
FROM Result
GROUP BY DOG, AGE, GENDER
```

Result for above query:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks curiousKid that did it not familiar with pivot tables I'll have to analyze what you did